# Domain/subdomain and server certificates for multi instances configuration

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, https, elastic-beanstalk

I build app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (it is a  load balancer with set of instances working behind him).

I want to add subdomain for my elastic beanstalk and use SSL. I can set HTTPS on load balancer. However, I need to set it also on instances working behind him.

1. Is it possible to bind my subdomain to load balancer and use server certificates on instances behind him?

My reason is that I have to validate client certificate on my instances via nginx. But to verify client certificate, I need to use also SSL with server certificates.

2. Is it possible that instances behind load balancer use the same server certificate and these instances are not under any subdomain - also not under subdomain registred in server certificates?

Comment: This AWS guide explains how to accomplish the SSL authentication behind the load balancer: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html#create-https-lb-clt